# Convert CryptoJS to Python

Tags: python, node.js, cryptojs, pycryptodome

I'm trying to follow some node.js code and convert it into python. I'm now left with the decryption part and I'm struggling:

```
const CryptoJS = require("crypto-js")

const ee = "#3vlsc6mdk2k400$"
const encrypt_data = "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"

var nn = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(ee)
var rr = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(ee.toUpperCase())
var ii = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypt_data, nn, {
    iv: rr,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
})

var xx = ii.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)
var out = JSON.parse(xx);
```

I've got as far as:

```
import json

from Cryptodome.Util.Padding import pad
from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES


def decrypt():
    ee = "#3vlsc6mdk2k400$"
    encrypt_data = "hlXzkPyyhwUYql2Nwl/3AAcRSsZHKf5LyqsAHqSWjP+ZHzfdmQ7bG2cOrf3YxwcZFIlsJNLJOSL/dSj/fFtjWHkeQd21inSUPOkbu2hSD2xMxEkyss8rOIVJAx6NmY9sap852VtmTc2CT4TdXXRduEK4fXASReIX3Eb9V+TMs24t5ow6w8aau+GWZLP9b32ALs4IZeea+dE3YcKtYrZOu/bV7ZLSawlontkgGN9s4QSjUhv43ifxkS6oDHGFkh+4pjjqfLDa2c0fA28otRZUF4uz+UvYAW2b9hZxBVJQU0E45Bf/myuQjZ14KtQr0NdxAMq53PZlki2hRVtnCDErA2e26cK9/bkC6Pz/J0N7rosTYw6TtDRGPYeqM3z645Uew3f3vEcSQLkWWxi1txQPxTbn1MT4HzRtnAbGJOF+GeaAKbwtSt2B86iHjkyEJ+ssmIMsARRjUmhdFmsMF6vuqA5pSgxvYTacg/yzZvy6HVhZBqTpPcaRJGt41efib3zQg8u++yKXdz8MnHicuz32w/osWzcMsC3Cwm5/a1tJZ48xFJdu8YgUsFS6ioNaO9V6vWz8imQZiPEZxd1FLfRynjS8LpvY3+83M2h+A0oExmcd4UaEMCqkklM1A7ssOXeDTqKS8UiZVM3zH6lzNI42QOZE+WYcPvwNzVLanJpZcKqlLupGfOiHuUclEwKrBL8h3wHtU6UmU+VoPJQM82b4pv5vJY/qlUgjLnaWk18A5UV9MF2b81iI3T8i4U8KGeovMhVLdq7YRZFdBG9djQgPRzwfofB/LRz5+aTwKwiTTsmvy4DMP/2iCB7Eiqr7OaKtuaj1n6vt2MdIstqTz/nDEkjLcdrspajdqHnTfUYLEVJvns6KPIKQaQ61I71G7vkEG4MtZ3PRgGy7/zR/B2qAzhaJmHYMZtOfE2OPcPXi3wi9tTYObYaGzpQIqkFGUtpa862bq8qMSXVUpfb8dvDTOyuvURD9FmSHeDHiO6DYhqxqQrfw1aRHK0vu6QcSsGF31vYnrRGR48nZgouqyzUv90Nc9hvyXBcEaYZpCG2qbAArBseD+RRtXeWV1yvV+C7oy68JOxgLJaL1AsLPX81WV9maPy2Ns3IJ64iNvKMebWFtETNtDPIs5amm+wFjERiQ85DK70wucEd3lWWQr7UddSO8U72whJXGbtsC2onskI75uLF3n7XX4goaHrj0IVB3kVqc4O1zMXWvCzype2EerR2E9K/qoBWh5PQRc4bPhrNdoYGSAh18AKtzVOqPgNgzXnW591r4pWMrWW8Tww89sayPZUnxOwDIaf6kFP74+34K+ZWKGVJA9YBPpKfGAfMgOYalnB7YMA4Tn4Hmt4OQtPeArwgR4DBW+HiQ+aFNK04="

    nn = ee.encode("utf-8")
    rr = ee.upper().encode("utf-8")

    cypher = AES.new(key=nn, mode=AES.MODE_CBC, iv=rr)
    encode_data = encrypt_data.encode("utf-8")
    padded_data = pad(
        data_to_pad=encode_data,
        block_size=16,
        style="pkcs7",
    )
    ii = cypher.decrypt(padded_data)
    xx = ii.decode("utf-8")
    out = json.loads(xx)
    return out


if __name__ == "__main__":
    decrypt()
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xaf in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: In the Python code, you must not pad the ciphertext before decryption, instead the decrypted data must be unpadded. Also, the ciphertext must be Base64 decoded before decryption. Then decryption with the Python code works.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Topaco for the pointers. Hopefully the below will help the other people work through the process of conversion...

```
import base64
import json

from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES
from Cryptodome.Util.Padding import unpad


def decrypt():
    ee = "#3vlsc6mdk2k400$"
    encrypt_data = "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"

    nn = ee.encode("utf-8")
    rr = ee.upper().encode("utf-8")

    cypher = AES.new(key=nn, mode=AES.MODE_CBC, iv=rr)
    decode_data = base64.b64decode(encrypt_data)
    decrypted_data=cypher.decrypt(decode_data)
    ii = unpad(padded_data=decrypted_data, block_size=16, style="pkcs7")
    xx = ii.decode("utf-8")
    out = json.loads(xx)
    return out


if __name__ == "__main__":
    decrypt()
```